# MySQL:Trying to run CUBE query -> Error in your sql syntax | LIMIT 0,25

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, olap-cube

I have query in my structure trying run in PHPMYADMIN. I am trying to run CUBE query for OLAP operation, this is my query :

```
SELECT QUARTER, REGION, SUM(SALES)
FROM salestable
GROUP BY CUBE (QUARTER, REGION)
```

I have also tried this query :

```
SELECT salestable.QUARTER, salestable.REGION, SUM(salestable.SALES)
FROM salestable
GROUP BY CUBE (salestable.QUARTER, salestable.REGION)
```

but it showing this error :

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(QUARTER, REGION) LIMIT 0, 25' at line 3
```

I tried to open the page to check syntax but it shows [page not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuhRE.png).

Comment: `GROUP BY col1, col2` **without parens** is the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think MySQL supports `CUBE` as a [`GROUP BY` modifier](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html), but you can use `WITH ROLLUP`:

```
SELECT st.QUARTER, st.REGION, SUM(st.SALES)
FROM salestable st
GROUP BY st.QUARTER, st.REGION WITH ROLLUP;
```